# Getting PHP Session ID while using Jquery load

Tags: php, jquery, session

I've created a site that is using Jquery's load function as follows to reload only parts of the site without the user having to reload the whole site, for example.

```
$('#divtoreload').load('refresh.php');
```

This works great except for now I need the refresh script to show different info (pulled for a database) based on the users session id. However using the `session_id();` function the session id doesn't seem to be pulled into the code so the database result returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put session_start() on your refresh.php

Comment: a quick explanation would be that when you ajax refresh.php you are like opening another url so unlike if refresh.php is `include`ed it won't get the `$_SESSION` variable

Answer (score 1):

Did you call `session_start();` before you called `session_id();`? You must start the session in order to access any session variables.

Comment: `session_start()` is called at the top of the index.php (the page where all this Jquery loading is going on.

Comment: he means on the called page through ajax on `refresh.php`